# terraria on the xbox 360 valid housing glitched?

Tags: terraria-console

I have built a massive house with several rooms for npcs. The house is has red ice walls and snow floor and roof as well as gray brick walls all placed myself. I have torches in every room and when I check valid housing it simply says this housing is missing a table and a chair. I've tried serial different tables wrenches and chairs and every time I check it now it says this in not valid housing. Any idea why? Is my game glitched or something?

Comment: Workbenches not wrenches..

Comment: red ice walls ? is there crimson around ?

Comment: I got the red ice blocks from a crimson area. But there the area was on a different world and this world doesn't have crimson. does that mean my house is corrupt and could this be why it's not working?

Comment: http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/The_Crimson thanks Anton for helping me realise what I did and why it won't work crimson is alternatively corruption. And thanks Angus Atkinson for letting me know how npcs accept there housing and how far they need to be away from it..